# Can I poll firewall counters on Juniper routers via SNMP

Tags: juniper, snmp, juniper-mx

I have a firewall counter on a Juniper MX router (`set firewall filter myfilter term myterm then count mycounter`) and want to poll its packet/byte count via SNMP. I searched for an OID but I'm unable to find one. Is it possible at all to poll firewall filter counters via SNMP and if so which MIB/OID do I use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this data is populated in the Firewall MIB

- .1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.5.2.1.5 contains your counters
- .1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.5.2.1.6 contains your filter names
- .1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.5.2.1.7 contains your counter names

show firewall filter RE-FILTER | match mgmt_ntp
mgmt_ntp           **199728**                 2628

% snmpbulkwalk jnpr .1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.5.2.1.7|grep mgmt_ntp
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.5.2.1.7.**9.82.69.45.70.73.76.84.69.82.8.109.103.109.116.95.110.116.112.2** = STRING: "mgmt_ntp"

% snmpbulkwalk jnpr .1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.5.2.1.5.**9.82.69.45.70.73.76.84.69.82.8.109.103.109.116.95.110.116.112.2**
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.5.2.1.5.9.82.69.45.70.73.76.84.69.82.8.109.103.109.116.95.110.116.112.2 = Counter64: **199728**

More information on [juniper.net](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos/topics/concept/mib-firewall-junos-overview.html)

Comment: Don't know how I missed that in the first place. Thanks.